# E/MediaPlayer: error (-19, 0) - for no reason

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've read countless topics regarding this error, however none of them had the same problem as me.

I am getting the

***E/MediaPlayer: error (-19, 0)***

***E/MediaPlayer: Error (-19,0)***

errors, however, The music does not even play. In the first few tries, it worked perfectly, but then one time the music played entirely, and then the app closed, and since then every time I open the app the music **doesn't even start**,

my code is extremely simple, this is the code I am using to test (inside onCreate in main activity):

```
    mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.shavingmirror_bgmusic);
    mp1.start();
```

The original code that used to work, but now for some reason doesn't (located inside a new class's onCreate, not in main activity), which basically only has a SeekBar and the music's volume should go up&down accordingly to the SeekBar:

```
public class settings extends AppCompatActivity implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

MediaPlayer mp;
SeekBar sb;
AudioManager am;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);
    sb = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.volumesb);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.shavingmirror_bgmusic);
    mp.start();
    mp.setLooping(true);

    am=(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int max = am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    sb.setMax(max);
    sb.setProgress(max/2);
    am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,max/2,0);
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mp.release();
}


@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,progress,0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was I didn't release the mp, causing it to crash and never work again. In order to fix this:

- Restart the emulator.
- Add some releases to it ( mp.release(); )

Hopefully this problem will not repeat itself, as now I am releasing the mp everytime. If it repeats itself, I will update this.